# How to debug program that doesn't like Alt+Tab?

Tags: decompiling, disassembly, ida

I am trying to fix an obscure bug in an old game by running it with IDA. The trouble is, the game runs fullscreen in 800x600 resolution and REALLY doesn't like being minimized, which makes it more or less impossible to actually use IDA while the game is running.

How might I approach this problem?

Comment: Two monitors usually works. Game on one, debugger on the other.